# How to fix io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient, vertx-eventbus

I was making a vertx verticle for Java. When I run it in IntelliJ it seems to start, but when I make a shadowjar and launch it on my Ubuntu server I get this:

```
INFO: Failed to bind on port: 8000
May 23, 2020 3:23:11 PM io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager
SEVERE: Failed to start http server
io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to start http server
```

It used to work normally before but I can't figure out what this means.
I have been using shadowjar to deploy this for weeks before, it gives no errors in IntelliJ and this error gives zero information...

Comment: The first line shows: `Failed to bind on port: 8000`. Is something already bound to port 8000 on the server? It seems this was logged by the app so if more info is needed perhaps the cause should be logged too.